# countries, states and cities in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I need to do a screen where I ask rails country condition and dynamic city in a country that when you choose to filter the cities of that particular country as I can do in rails or if any gem for that thanks

Answer (score 0):

RoR won'r help in this case. It's work most for javascript. 
You should find a javascript plugin to do this or write your own code and load cities after choosing country using AJAX.

I think [Chained combobox](http://codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Don't remember now what should it be.

Comment: You can make populate an combobox with countries with rails, then show it to the user. After user selects specific country, javascrpt comes into game. With ajax you should make a call to rails backend, and it should return the list of cities. After that you should populate combobox with cities that are returned from backend.